# I am getting an error even I am getting the variable values (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensor

I am running this code, and I am facing a problem with the code at some point.

```
a = ['C', 'c1', 'c2']
b = ['p3', 'p1', 'p4', 'p2']
print(a)
print (b)
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, columns=b, index=a) for x in matrix]),keys=a)
print(df)
```

this is the output the error I am having:

```
    ['C', 'c1', 'c2']
    ['p3', 'p1', 'p4', 'p2']



          File "M:\Eclipse\hey\Main_Graph.py", line 83, in Main_Graph
            df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, columns=b, index=a) for x in matrix])
          File "M:\Eclipse\hey\Main_Graph.py", line 83, in <listcomp>
            df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, columns=b, index=a) for x in matrix])
        NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

I want this kind of output:

```
        C   c1   c2
C  p1  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p2  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p3  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p4  0.0  0.0  0.0
c1 p1  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p2  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p3  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p4  0.0  0.0  0.0
c2 p1  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p2  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p3  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p4  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: what do you mean by values and what do you expect to have ?

Comment: What is matrix in the for loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve].  It is not clear how exactly your inputs relate to your outputs.  For example, why is `type` seemingly ignored, and why do only some of your values show up as columns and row labels?

Comment: I updated the question now, and here Matrix is a 3-dimensional Matrix(3,4,3)

Comment: `pd` is undefined in the code you provided - what's `pd`?

Comment: it is an object of Pandas